# Is CDH(Cloudera Distribution for hadoop) is open source to use?

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

Is CDH(Cloudera Distribution for hadoop) is open source to use or is it commercial?

Any inputs on this greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

["All software developed by Cloudera for CDH is released with an Apache 2.0 license"](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDHDOC/Apache+and+Third-Party+Licenses).

In other words, it is open source.

Answer (score 5):

Cloudera contributes to apache hadoop in many ways. Some of them are open source and free to use and some are not open source and commercial.

Cloudera adds **their own features to base apache hadoop** (eg: human readable option in hadoop file system commands: "hadoop fs -df **-h**" , "hadoop fs -du **-h**" and a lot more.. ) these are open source under apache license.

**Cloudera manager** is the hadoop management tool from cloudera for managing hadoop eco systems which is **not open source** and available in **free editions and enterprise editions**.

Comment: Cloudera Express includes a free version of Cloudera Manager. The Cloudera Enterprise version of Cloudera Manager provides additional functionality. Both the Cloudera Express and Cloudera Enterprise versions automate the installation, configuration, and monitoring of CDH on an entire cluster.

Answer (score 2):

The Enterprise CDH Hadoop version is open source from Cloudera, though if your enterprise is looking for support services from Cloudera then one has to pay for support services.

Cloudera Manager and Cloudera Navigator is Hadoop Cluster management and Hadoop data governance tool respectively, which is propitiatory to Cloudera.